# Firefox or Ubuntu browsers not connecting to WiFi but WiFi connected OK

Tags: firefox

Firefox or Ubuntu browsers not connecting to wifi. wifi connected ok and working on MS Windows laptop.  Newly installed Ubuntu on Acer Aspire laptop.  Firefox connects to wifi sometimes for a short while then shows a message, "server not found"  Ubuntu browser has never worked, tried several times, same message.

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue. Try setting your DNS to something static such as 8.8.4.4 in network-manager to see if that fixes the issue. Also, for firefox, you need to go into about:config and disable ipv6 if you are using ipv4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i experienced this couple weeks ago with a fresh 16.04 installed.  Wireless will work and about 5 - 10 minutes later, internet will not work, you can disconnect but cannot reconnect.  The only way to get it back is by rebooting.

After hours of searching, finally found a solution that would work.  Credit to this post here.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262104&page=2

Basically, you need to update your driver for your wireless chipset.
Full instruction is here
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, wifi connected but browser isn't accessing network.  I solved it by changing the router wireless mode from b,g,n to just g,n.

Be real, be sober.

Answer (score 0):

### Heading ##Reinstall Ubuntu

Hi folks,
I found a solution to my problem with the browser not staying connected to my WiFi.  It might not suit everyone but as a new user anything that I am able to implement is great.  I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 from a second download of Ubuntu to a different disc, in case there were any bugs with the first.

Downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 to a new disc using a different laptop

On the host laptop for Ubuntu - steps I took to boot from new CD:

Connected the Ethernet cable

Loaded DVD disc

Press F2 on reboot

Arrow across to Boot Manager and down to CD Rom

Press F10, select YES
(screen goes back to boot-up)

Press F12, select CD Rom

Press Return
(Boot-up from CD should start)

You will be given a number of options as the Reinstall recognises the existing Ubuntu.  You can overwrite the existing/badly installed version.

Download upgrades via Ethernet cable

When connecting the reinstalled Ubuntu to your WiFi, disconnect the Ethernet cable and make sure that the WiFi is switched off on any other devices with the same net-key.

Please tick this answer if it has been of help.

All the best

Barney